# How to use Jira rest APIs in WebHooks with Oauth authoization

Tags: oauth, jira, attachment, webhooks, jira-rest-api

I have a requirement to download attachments from Jira during event triggers and upload back to other supporting tool. For this purpose, started using WebHooks, during event trigger, json values will get passed thru post call. I have found Jira rest api also to get attachment download link to use it in webhooks. But this rest api requires valid authentication. I can't use basic login details to hard code in the script for downloading through URL.

How can I authorize this URL for getting the attachment. I heard that, we can establish OAuth and for this I need to enable application linking. At this stage, I am not sure how can I link the WebHook URL as an application. Current Hook is not a complete application it just accepts json as post and parses through it.

Need your support how to enable this OAuth and how to create that app. I am newbie to this WebHooks and OAuth concepts. so bare me for the generic queries .. :)

If there are any other possible solutions for my requirement are also welcomed.

Thank you..